# Serialization of a basic sum type in Json with Aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

```
type GoalDescription = Text

data GoalStatus = Created | Accomplished | InProgress | GivenUp deriving (Show , Eq , Generic )

data Goal = Goal {workspaceId ::WorkspaceId , goalId :: GoalId , description :: GoalDescription , status :: GoalStatus} deriving (Show , Eq , Generic )

instance ToJSON Goal where
  toJSON (Goal {workspaceId, goalId ,description,status } ) = object [
            "workspaceId" .= workspaceId,
            "goalId" .= goalId,
            "description" .= description,
            "status" .= status]

instance FromJSON Goal  where

    parseJSON (Object jsonObject) = Goal <$> jsonObject .: "workspaceId" <*>  jsonObject .: "goalId" <*>  jsonObject .: "description" <*>  jsonObject .: "status"
    parseJSON _ =  error $ "Json format not expected"
```

I want to implement the FromJSON and ToJSON of GoalStatus that way: `Goal {.. status:"accomplished"}` or `Goal {.. status:"inProgress"}` etc... somehow I don't know how to implement these type classes without having a key -> value structure... `GoalStatus` should be only converted into a `String Text` without Keys attached to the value..

I have this temporary solution where I had to add an unnecessary key named "value" :

```
instance ToJSON GoalStatus where
    toJSON (Created) = object ["value" .= String "created"]
    toJSON (InProgress) = object ["value" .= String "inProgress"]
    toJSON (Accomplished) = object ["value" .= String "accomplished"]
    toJSON (GivenUp) = object ["value" .= String "GivenUp"]


instance FromJSON GoalStatus  where

  parseJSON (Object o) = do
     value <- o .: "value"
     case value of
          String status | (unpack status) == "created" -> return Created
          String status | (unpack status) == "inProgress" -> return InProgress
          String status | (unpack status) == "accomplished" -> return Accomplished
          String status | (unpack status) == "accomplished" -> return GivenUp
          _ -> error $ "Json format not expected"
  parseJSON _ =  error $ "Json format not expected"
```

Comment: A string is valid JSON, have you tried returning just the string (not an object) in `ToJSON` of `GoalStatus`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String !Text` is a constructor of `Value` and `object` has the type signature `[Pair] -> Value` where `Pair` is `(Text, Value)`. You can use `String` to make the `Value` in `ToJSON` and then match on the particular shapes of the `String` when parsing in `FromJSON`.

```hs
instance ToJSON GoalStatus where
  toJSON (Created) = String "created"
  toJSON (InProgress) = String "inProgress"
  toJSON (Accomplished) = String "accomplished"
  toJSON (GivenUp) = String "givenUp"

instance FromJSON GoalStatus  where
  parseJSON (String s) = case unpack s of
    "created" -> return Created
    "inProgress" -> return InProgress
    "accomplished" -> return Accomplished
    "givenUp" -> return GivenUp
    _ -> error $ "Json format not expected"
  parseJSON _ =  error $ "Json format not expected"
```

Comment: Doing some code golf here. I find the `with*` functions from `Data.Aeson` handy.  For example, `parseJSON = withString "GoalStatus" $ \case "created" -> ...` would emit a useful error when the Value constructor isn't `String`.  The same goes for `withObject` and Henin's FromJSON instance for Goal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand the question. Here's a full file with generic-derived implementations:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
module Q54178405 where

import Data.Text
import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics

type WorkspaceId = Int
type GoalId = Int
type GoalDescription = Text

data GoalStatus =
  Created | Accomplished | InProgress | GivenUp deriving (Show, Eq, Generic)

instance ToJSON GoalStatus
instance FromJSON GoalStatus

data Goal = Goal {
    workspaceId ::WorkspaceId
  , goalId :: GoalId
  , description :: GoalDescription
  , status :: GoalStatus}
  deriving (Show, Eq, Generic)

instance ToJSON Goal
instance FromJSON Goal
```

Here's how it behaves in GHCi:

```
*Q54178405 Q54178405> encode $ Goal 42 1337 "foo" Accomplished
"{\"status\":\"Accomplished\",\"goalId\":1337,\"workspaceId\":42,\"description\":\"foo\"}"
*Q54178405 Q54178405> encode $ Goal 42 1337 "foo" GivenUp
"{\"status\":\"GivenUp\",\"goalId\":1337,\"workspaceId\":42,\"description\":\"foo\"}"
```

Isn't that what you want?

The instances round-trip as well:

```
*Q54178405 Q54178405> decode $ encode $ Goal 42 1337 "foo" GivenUp :: Maybe Goal
Just (Goal {workspaceId = 42, goalId = 1337, description = "foo", status = GivenUp})
```

If this isn't what you want, it'd be useful with some explicit examples of input with desired output.